# How to return button background color to default after second push?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton, background-color

I am working on a app. There is a button. When you push on it its background becomes green. How make it return to default color after pressing it one more time. And green again after next time?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}


@IBAction func keyPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably change and check the `UIButton`'s `isSelected` property for that simple thing, like this:

```
@IBAction func keyPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if sender.isSelected {
        sender.backgroundColor = .clear
    } else {
        sender.backgroundColor = .green
    }
    sender.isSelected.toggle()
}
```

Comment: I corrected the code according to your suggestion. But when I pressed on button first time it becomes blue with rounded corners and when press again it becomes green with square corners. though default color of the button background was gray, orange etc. what it the issue? ![image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/25geeflxms0lk6s/image.png?dl=0)

Comment: @sakumashigeru well, in this code I presume that the default color is `clear` (3rd line `sender.backgroundColor = .clear`) you can change that if you want. As for the rounded corners, the above code is certainly not responsible for that.